# How to get rid of tick marks for compass plots in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, label

I'm trying to create a large plot with many subplots in MATLAB, with the very center plot being a compass. However, I'd like to just display the arrows in the compass, and NOT the tick marks around the side. I know that when using the normal plot function, you can simply type:

```
set(h,'XTick',[],'YTick',[]);
```

But I was wondering if there is an analogue when plotting with the `compass` function.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that easy, unfortunately. From the Mathworks support site [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-DRAF4Z/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-DRAF4Z), you'll have to do something like:

```
set(findall(gcf, 'String', '30', '-or','String','60') ,'String', ' ');
```

That is, you need to find each tick mark and set it to a string with just a space. You can probably build up the required command and then do an eval on it.

Comment: I have it a shot, and used the code, but it didn't work for me. To be clear, I'm evaluating 
`subplot(6,3,[8 11]);

compass([0 1 1/sqrt(2) -1 0 -1/sqrt(2) -1/sqrt(2) 1/sqrt(2)], [1 0 1/sqrt(2) 0 -1 -1/sqrt(2) 1/sqrt(2) -1/sqrt(2)]);

set(findall(gca, 'String', '30', '-or','String','60') , ' ');`